# Extract the date string from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all datetime substrings from the below sample string that start with `CAST(` and end with `DateTime)`:

```
CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime), 1, '98ac498b-89b6-434a-808d-020e82a59c82't, CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime), 1, 4, CAST(0x0000A20000C7558A AS DateTime)
```

**Edit**

I want to find out all the individual entries like `CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime)` from the string.

Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

`/(CAST\([^\)]* AS DateTime\))/g`

Matches:

```
CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime)
CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime)
CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime)
CAST(0x0000A20000C7558A AS DateTime)
```

Sample code:

```
var re = /(CAST\([^\)]* AS DateTime\))/g; 
var str = 'CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime), 1, \'98ac498b-89b6-434a-808d-020e82a59c82\'t, CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A20000C35DF7 AS DateTime), 1, 4, CAST(0x0000A20000C7558A AS DateTime)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV3dW5/4)

Comment: I want to find out all the individual entries - CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime) from the string.  Since I need to replace CAST(0x0000A21E000DD2C1 AS DateTime) with some other string.

Comment: /(CAST\([^\)]* AS DateTime\))/g  - This one works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ChetanKalore: Glad I could help you. Can you please upvote and mark as answered?